# How to print Listboxtext to pdf in C# using Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, desktop

I have been working on an app, and am using **dapper** to map the data and data access from database.

I have a form for teams and players. I have coded so that when I click on a team name it displays players in that team. I want to print the players of a specific team to a **pdf file**. The following is the code for what I'm trying to do; moreover I'm attaching pictures for better understanding.

I want to print players in the `listbox` to a pdf file, with the pictures of each player.

[image for manage teams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DcJNk.png)

```
private void printButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (teamsListBox.SelectedItem is TeamModel selectedTeam)
    {
        playersListBox.DataSource = selectedTeam.Players;
        nameValue.Text = playersListBox.Name;
        printDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
        nameValue.Text = playersListBox.Name;
        SetBindings();
        string items = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < selectedTeam.Players.Count; i++)
        {
            PlayerModel item = selectedTeam.Players[i];
            items += Name.ToString() + " ";

        }
        MessageBox.Show(items);
        myReader = new StringReader(items);
        if (printDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.printDocument1.Print();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to loop on the player names and image path and send them to your pdf file, this is an easy code to create a PDF with players list using [PDFFlow library](https://go.pdfflow.io/pdf_lib)

```
    {
        var imagePath = "imageFile.png";
        var numType = NumerationStyle.Arabic;
        DocumentBuilder.New()
        .AddSection()
            .AddParagraph("Cristiano Ronaldo").SetListNumbered(numType, 1).AddInlineImage(imagePath, 20, 20, ScalingMode.UserDefined).ToSection()
            .AddParagraph("Lionel Messi").SetListNumbered(numType, 1).AddInlineImage(imagePath, 20, 20, ScalingMode.UserDefined).ToSection()
            .AddParagraph("Ronaldinho").SetListNumbered(numType, 1).AddInlineImage(imagePath, 20, 20, ScalingMode.UserDefined).ToDocument()
        .Build("Result.pdf");}
```

The result will be like this:

[image]